# How to show column values based on column names in two dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a drop down menu; having column names from database table. Now, I have another dropdown menu.

What I want is; When I select column name from first dropdown menu, It shows the values of that selected column name from database table in second dropdown menu.

I have inserted column names for the first dropdown menu in options tag but i want to retrieve all column values based on selected column name from database table.

Here is my code:

```
<select name="first">

  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select an Option</option> 
  <option value="all">Select All</option>   
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
  <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
```

Where `a,b,c,d` are the column names. Please help me out.

Comment: simple : call ajax on change of column dropdown and get the values and populate it on other dropdown...

Comment: you can use ajax: https://www.mitrajit.com/populate-dropdown-list-based-selection-another-dropdown-list-using-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

**HTML:**

```
    <select name="category">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="1" rel="accessories">Novels</option>
    <option value="2" rel="sports">Scooties</option>
    <option value="3" rel="cars">Bikes</option>
</select>


<select name="items" class="cascade">
    <option value="3" class="accessories">Immortals of meluha/option>
    <option value="8" class="accessories">Half Girlfriend</option>
    <option value="1" class="sports">Active 5G</option>
    <option value="4" class="sports">Active 4G</option>
    <option value="6" class="cars">Royal Enfield</option>
    <option value="2" class="cars">Pulsor</option>
</select>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $cat = $('select[name=category]'),
        $items = $('select[name=items]');

    $cat.change(function(){
        var $this = $(this).find(':selected'),
            rel = $this.attr('rel'),
            $set = $items.find('option.' + rel);

        if ($set.size() < 0) {
            $items.hide();
            return;
        }

        $items.show().find('option').hide();

        $set.show().first().prop('selected', true);
    });
  });
```

Comment: But i want to retrieve values in second dropdown menu from database table

Comment: yes in html i used values static you can get values from database as dynamic

Comment: Do i have to use SQL query for this

Comment: Please help me with this. I can't understand this

Comment: ok tell me did you create any tables for that and tell me what data you want exactly

Comment: Yes I have created table having columns with column names a,b,c,d as i mentioned above. Each column has data in number of rows. I want to show the values of column A (i.e. rows of column A) in second dropdown menu when i select A in first dropdown menu

Comment: so where you saved the second dropdown values?did you save in table

Comment: Yes i saved them in the table in database